# Can I create a loop with a counter in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

There seem to be quite a few similar questions, but none of them helped me. I'd like to refactor the following piece of XSLT:

```
<fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="table-item-bordered">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="/forms//instance[@versionNumber = '1']/content//textbox[@id = $id]/text()" />
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="table-item-bordered">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="/forms//instance[@versionNumber = '2']/content//textbox[@id = $id]/text()" />
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="table-item-bordered">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="/forms//instance[@versionNumber = '3']/content//textbox[@id = $id]/text()" />
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Note the changing versionNumber attribute.

The xml source looks something like this:

```
<forms>
  <instance versionNumber="3">
    <content>
      <textbox id="1">THREE</textbox>
    </content>
    <previousVersions>
      <instance versionNumber="1">
        <content>
          <textbox id="1">ONE</textbox>
        </content>
      </instance>
      <instance versionNumber="2">
        <content>
          <textbox id="1">TWO</textbox>
        </content>
      </instance>
    </previousVersions>
  </instance>
</forms>
```

The output should be a table row formatted like this:

```
+-----+-----+-------+
| ONE | TWO | THREE |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

In code this will look something like this:

```
<table-cell>ONE</table-cell>
<table-cell>TWO</table-cell>
<table-cell>THREE</table-cell>
```

This would be easy enough without using a loop counter, however I always want need 3 cells, regardless of how many versions there are. If there is no instance with versionNumber=3, the table needs to look like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| ONE | TWO |     |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Or in XML:

```
<table-cell>ONE</table-cell>
<table-cell>TWO</table-cell>
<table-cell></table-cell>
```

Comment: You don't need loop counters in XSLT. What is `$instanceId` and `$id`? Also show the relevant part of your input and the output you want to create. Maybe these variables are not necessary.

Comment: I've updated the question. I would prefer not to use loop-counters, as xslt is a functional language which does away with loops. In a functional language I might call 'map' on the set [1, 2, 3] and go from there, is there an XSLT equivalent of doing that?

Comment: Please post your expected output **as code**.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I've posted code of the same schema of what I expect to be created. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @michael.hor257k, I ended up not looping, but creating a named template and calling that 3 times. This was satisfying enough to reduce code duplication and make it read cleaner:

```
<xsl:call-template name="table-cell">
    <xsl:with-param name="node" select="/forms//instance[@versionNumber = '1']/content//textbox[@id = $id]" />
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:call-template name="table-cell">
    <xsl:with-param name="node" select="/forms//instance[@versionNumber = '2']/content//textbox[@id = $id]" />
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:call-template name="table-cell">
    <xsl:with-param name="node" select="/forms//instance[@versionNumber = '3']/content//textbox[@id = $id]" />
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="tableCell">
    <xsl:param name="node" />
    <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="table-item-bordered">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="$node/text()" />
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Without loop but with additional template:

```
<xsl:template match="instance">
  <xsl:param name="id" />

  <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="table-item-bordered">
    <fo:block>
      <xsl:value-of select="content//textbox[@id = $id]/text()" />
    </fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:template>

<!-- in another template... -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="/forms//instance[@id = $instanceId and (@versionNumber &gt;= 1 and @versionNumber &lt;= 3)]">
  <xsl:with-param name="id" select="$id"/>
  <xsl:sort select="@versionNumber" data-type="number"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Comment: Oops, missed this table-cell. Thanks, Tomalak.

Comment: No problem. I was writing up the same thing when I saw your answer popping up. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rudolf. Sorry I wasn't clear in the question originally but I need to have exactly 3 table cells regardless of how many instance nodes there are, even if there are only 1 or 2.

Answer (score 2):

> I always want need 3 cells, regardless of how many versions there are.

With only three cells, you could simply hard-code them as yo have done. If you don't want to do that, then you *will* have to use a loop, for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="instance" match="instance" use="@versionNumber" />

<xsl:template match="/forms">
    <root>
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-cells">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="3" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-cells">
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:if test="$n">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-cells">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <!-- current cell -->
        <table-cell>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('instance', $n)/content/textbox" />
        </table-cell>
    </xsl:if>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> In a functional language I might call 'map' on the set [1, 2, 3] and
>   go from there, is there an XSLT equivalent of doing that?

In XSLT 2.0, you can do:

```
<xsl:template match="/forms">
    <xsl:variable name="forms" select="." />
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="('1','2','3')">
            <table-cell>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('instance', ., $forms)/content/textbox" />
            </table-cell>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Or even:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to 3">
        <table-cell>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('instance', string(.), $forms)/content/textbox" />
        </table-cell>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

> I need to have exactly 3 table cells regardless of how many instance nodes there are, even if there are only 1 or 2.

Then you could use a little trick and loop over three unrelated nodes and abuse `position()`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//*[position() &lt;= 3]">
  <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />

  <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="table-item-bordered">
    <fo:block>
      <xsl:value-of select="content/forms//instance[@versionNumber = $i]//textbox[@id = $id]/text()" />
    </fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:for-each>
```

or you could use recursion, which is a little more idiomatic for XSLT. It works for arbitrary amounts of repetition but it's also longer:

```
<xsl:template name="output-table-cell">
  <xsl:param name="i" />
  <xsl:param name="max" />

  <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $max">
    <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="table-item-bordered">
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="content/forms//instance[@versionNumber = $i]//textbox[@id = $id]/text()" />
      </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>

    <!-- recursive step -->
    <xsl:call-template name="output-table-cell">
      <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1" />
      <xsl:with-param name="max" select="$max" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that I assume `$id` to be defined elsewhere in both snippets. Adapt as needed.